# Using JOIN and SUM returns unwanted null row when WHERE condition is not met

Tags: mysql, join, sum

Please consider the following query:

Select all `payment`s of a user and `UNION` the results with the user's `invoice`s.

```
SELECT `id`,
       `amount` AS `value`,
       'PAYMENT' AS `transaction_type`
    FROM `payment`
    WHERE `user_id` = $user_id

UNION ALL

SELECT `i`.`id`,
       (-1) * SUM(`ii`.`unit_price` * `ii`.`quantity`) AS `value`,
       'INVOICE' AS `transaction_type`
    FROM `invoice` `i`
    JOIN `invoiceitem` `ii` ON `ii`.`invoice_id` = `i`.`id`
    WHERE `user_id` = $user_id AND `type` = 'invoice'
```

**The problem** is that for users that have no payment and no invoice, an unwanted row is returned like this:

```
id   | value | transaction_type
=================================
NULL | 0     | NULL
```

But for users that have some data, the result is completely expected.

---

### **IMPORTANT EDIT**

After some more research, I got that the problem should be from the second subquery below:

```
SELECT i.id,
        (-1) * SUM(ii.unit_price * ii.quantity) AS `value`,
        'INVOICE' AS `trans_type`
FROM invoice i
JOIN invoiceitem ii ON ii.invoice_id = i.id
WHERE user_id = 4 AND type = 'invoice'
```

which returns the following:

```
id   | value | transaction_type
=================================
NULL | NULL  | INVOICE
```

Of course the user with `user_id = 4` has not yet any invoice. But for another user that has some invoices, the result is OK.

Comment: @aiias: that does nothing. `union all` simply returns all rows from both queries. `union` will return only non-duplicate rows.

Comment: Your question shows a "problem row" returned where **transaction_type** is null, but I don't see any way such a row is possible.  Neither of the two `SELECT` statements will return a null value for that column. Please post some sample data for all three tables to illustrate.

Comment: Thank you @BellevueBob. I edited the q after more investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to say with any certainty without understanding the complete table descriptions, but based on the update to your question, you need to eliminate rows that have NULL values for the column `i.id`:

```
SELECT  i.id
      , (-1) * SUM(ii.unit_price * ii.quantity) AS `value`
      , 'INVOICE' AS `trans_type`
FROM invoice i
JOIN invoiceitem ii 
ON   ii.invoice_id = i.id
WHERE user_id = 4 
  AND type = 'invoice'
  AND i.id IS NOT NULL
```

I'm guessing that there is a logical defect in your data model or there might be some other column you should use.  I can speculate that this `invoice` row could be a cancelled order, but it is clear that a row exists where the `id` column is null, which is why it appears in the result.

Comment: And I had to change `i.id IS NOT NULL` with `value IS NOT NULL` to work. Thank you very much `:)`

Comment: And it raised another error because I was going to use an alias (`value`) in `WHERE` clause, that was why I had to write `HAVING value IN NOT NULL` instead of using `WHERE`; I would thank if you edit your answer (or I will do that if it has not problem from your side)

Comment: Your question is really "too localized", especially since it seems you are working on different things (using a HAVING expression is completely irrelevant to the question as asked).  It sounds like you have an answer to your problem so I'd just leave it as-is.

Answer (score 3):

This row is created by the aggregate function `SUM`.  In order to prevent this, use a valid `GROUP BY` clause, probably `GROUP BY user_id`

Comment: I should thank for your try, but this did not work. At this time, `NULL` values where filled by some values that where completely wrong.

Comment: Your answer was more accurate to my problem and it's just edited.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid such nulls just use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`, so, replace your following sql line:

```
JOIN `invoiceitem` `ii` ON `ii`.`invoice_id` = `i`.`id`
```

for this one:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `invoiceitem` `ii` ON `ii`.`invoice_id` = `i`.`id`
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but writing `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead `JOIN` didn't also work. No difference between the two.